# How can I remove the task bar entry of a GTK# window?

Tags: .net, gtk, taskbar, gtk#

... Just like the [`ShowInTaskBar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar.aspx) property of a WinForms form.

Comment: What operating system are you targeting for this?

Comment: I saw this behavior on Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gtk.Window.SkipTaskbarHint](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?tlink=24@ecma:1455%23Window/P/25)

Comment: Theoretically, window managers are not required to respect the hint, although most modern WMs do. Are you on Windows by any chance? If so, it seems to be a GTK+ bug: http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtkmm-list/2009-April/msg00003.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm using such window (without taskbar entry) to display notifcations. I'm setting the window type to: **WindowType.Popup** via inherited constructor.

```
public class Notificator:Window
{
    public Notificator()
        : base(WindowType.Popup)
    {
```

This creates window that is not showing taskbar